# How best do I guard against undefined attributes?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Given an internal method that may call on one or more possibly undefined attributes which are nil, how does one best guard against this?

For instance, the following method makes several internal calls.

```
def penalty
    penalty = ((self.rate.to_f - comparative_rate)/100 * self.payments[:balance] * (self.months_to_maturity / 12.0)).round(2)
end
```

This method being one of them may not have a maturity_date defined since once wasn't provided. This may be a valid state

```
def months_to_maturity
    today = Date.today
    (self.maturity_date.year * 12 + self.maturity_date.month) - (today.year * 12 + today.month)
end
```

What's the best way to guard all the way down against nil? Is nil the valid state for a date which is undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nil` is perfectly valid for data that can be undefined (missed, not provided, etc.). However, your processing logic becomes more complex, since you need to define the behavior when your data is nil.

What comes to my mind is [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), that can help you with replacing your nulls with objects containing default behavior for null. Take a look at the excellent ruby implementation of this pattern: [naught](https://github.com/avdi/naught).

**EDIT**: Oh, I totally forgot about gorgeous talk by Sandi Metz [Nothing is Something](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29MAL8pJImQ). Really cool stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for these conditions in each of the methods and decide what is the right response (return nil, raise an error, etc.)  Not knowing your application it seems reasonable that `months_to_maturity` could return `nil` if `maturity_date` is also nil.  Assuming you agree that in this case `nil` means unknown or un-calculatable.

Then in `penalty` you could return `nil` if `months_to_maturity` returned `nil`. And similar for any other values that might be nil or result in an invalid calculation.

Or you can wrap the whole method in a begin/rescue block checking for ZeroDivisionError, but that might mask other issues.